# AWS IoT Button Won't Connect to AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I recently bought an AWS IoT Button generation 2, and I'm trying to set it up.

I followed the steps in this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-gs.html

I can connect to the wifi network generated by the button. I went to the .../index.html, attached my certs, etc.

Everything seemed fine, until I tried to use the button. When using the desktop-based instructions, I went to the MQTT Client and subscribed to it, but saw nothing when I clicked the button. When I tried to use the iOS app setup, I set the button action to send me a text message. I never got the text message. In both cases, the below occurred:

**When I click the button, it blinks white for about a minute, then 3 short red blinks (meaning there was an error connecting to the wireless network).**

I've tried these steps in my secure home network as well as the open network at my local library. Same results.

I've also tried starting over, repeating all steps from the tutorial and creating new certificates, etc. Same results.

Seems I'm not the only one having this [problem](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=800249&#800249).

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Spencer, did you integrate the IoT button with a Lambda function? Are you using SNS to send the SMS? Is your phone number validated? Did you take a look at CloudWatch logs? Is the Lambda function inside a VPC (that could explain it not connecting to the internet)? Sorry for the question bombing.

Comment: I didn't create a Lambda function, but while setting up in the app I added a pre-built "action" to send an SMS. This is probably a Lambda function. Not in a VPC that I know of... I don't think I can check CloudWatch logs unless it's for a custom Lambda function that I own, right?

Comment: @nkipreos       _______

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My button is now connected, although I have no idea why it wasn't working. I just followed the exact same steps I had been following on the same wifi network and everything, and all of a sudden it connected. Still looking for insight if anyone has some!